# Passing string to separate WebViewController doesn't take

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

I am new to Objective C and Xcode, but have come a long way in learning by following tutorials and searching on stack overflow. I have encountered a problem that I can’t seem to find a solution for. I know I must be doing something wrong (perhaps my storyboard is set up incorrectly). What I am attempting to do is load an embedded webpage in a second scene by pressing a button in the first scene. I need the button press to pass a NSString containing the URL address. I have tried various senders - the one I am currently using is:

```
- (IBAction)websiteButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    WebViewController *destinationController = [[WebViewController alloc]
        initWithString:self.webInfo];
    destinationController.webInfo = _webInfo;

}
```

The _webInfo is an NSString containing the URL.

The WebViewController .h file defines the initWithString as follows:

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)webInfo;
```

and the WebViewController .m file contains the following code:

```
@synthesize webUrl;


 - (id)initWithString:(NSString *)webInfo
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
   if (self) {
    webUrl = [webInfo copy];       
    }
   return self;
}
```

Inserting a breakpoint here indicates that the appropriate URL string is being passed to the WebViewController. However when the following ViewDidLoad code is executed, the webURL and webView are empty, even though webUrl had the appropriate NSString in the init.

```
 NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webUrl];  
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am totally baffled by this problem. I have tried a number of different approaches all with the same result. If I insert something like `NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];` in the ViewDidLoad, the Apple site is displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy solution will be you move the code from `viewDidLoad` to `initWithString`

or

create a setter methods for property `webInfo` and write code to load webView from url there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSString property in WebViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * webInfo;
```

then in your IBAction set the property

```
WebViewController *destinationController = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
destinationController.webInfo = @"YOUR URL";
```

don't forget to go to the new view (this example works if you're using a Navigation Controller

```
[self presentViewController:destinationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

then in your viewDidLoad do this

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_webInfo];  
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```